# How to handle memory management for Singleton pattern in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, singleton

My code is:

```
static Class1 *onlyInstance;
+(Class1*) getInstance {
  @synchronized([Class1 class]) {
  if(onlyInstance == nil)
    onlyInstance = [[Class1 alloc]init];
return onlyInstance;
 }
return nil;
}
```

How to manage memory with sington pattern in Objective-C?

Comment: you mean how you should clean up the singleton class?

Comment: I meant to say that when and where should I release the object onlyInstance that i allocated..How to manage memory with this type of static variable created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a singleton, you don't really need to release it at any given time, it is supposed to be around whenever you need it.

If you need to release it you can do that from within the class itself.

simply release the onlyInstance and set it to nil, so once the method that created it in the first place is called again it will recreate it.

Comment: But since i am returning that onlyInstance, how can i release it there?

Comment: autorelease, but then you wouldn't need a singleton but a simple method like + (MyClass *)myClass { return [[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease]; }